# How can I pass the type in a generic function in C#

Tags: c#, signalr

I have the following code:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct)]
    public class SignalRHub : Attribute
    {
        public readonly string Route;

        public SignalRHub(string Route)
        {
            this.Route = Route;
        }
    }

    [SignalRHub("hubpath")]
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {
        ...
    }
```

This defines a SignalR hub with an attribute to know the path.

I want to register hubs with the SignalRHub attribute dynamically, so I have the following code to find all hubs:

```
        // find all hubs
        var Hubs =
            from Assemblies in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().AsParallel()
            from Types in Assemblies.GetTypes()
            let Attributes = Types.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SignalRHub), true)
            where Attributes?.Length > 0
            select new { Type = Types };

        var HubsList = Hubs.ToList();
```

and then I want to register them, but this is where I have a problem:

```
        foreach (var H in HubsList)
        {
            // get the route attribute
            var Route = string.Empty;
            var Attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(H.Type);
            foreach (var Attribute in Attributes)
            {
                if (Attribute is SignalRHub A)
                {
                    Route = A.Route;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // register the hub
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Route))
            {
                Logging.Warn($"[Hub] {H.Type.Name} does not have a path, skipping");
            }
            else
            {
                Logging.Info($"[Hub] Registering {H.Type.Name} with path {Route}");
                Application.UseSignalR(R => R.MapHub<H>(Route)); <- this won't compile
            }
```

MapHub requires T to derive from Hub; with H being of type TestHub, it should be fine, but that syntax is not working.

How can I make this work?

Comment: use type instead of variable, like `Application.UseSignalR(R => R.MapHub<Hub>(Route)); `

Comment: You have to search for a non-generic MapHub accepting 2 parameters System.Type and Route

Comment: Not directly answering the question, but It seems you are trying to use the polymorphism  in a weird way. It would be better to wrap each attribute in about  class that knows how to dispatch it and your function will only call the dispatch/route method of the attribute. Then it becomes the responsibility of the attribute creator to choose the right attribute wrapper.

Comment: does that mean that using the type derived from (hub) is ok and I don't need to use the real type? @AndriyShevchenko, there is no non-generic MapHub call

Comment: @DrPhil, I don't understand; can you point to an example of this?

Comment: @Thomas Seems I found solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution (uses reflection)

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections;
//somewhere in your code
private static readonly MethodInfo mapperMethodInfo = 
    typeof(HubRouteBuilder).GetMethod(
        "MapHub",
        new Type [] { 
            typeof(PathString)
        },
        null
    );

// in your mapping code
// replace this:
Application.UseSignalR(R => R.MapHub<H>(Route));  

// with this
Application.UseSignalR(R => 
{
   // pay attention to use of H.Type, R and Route variables
   mapperMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(H.Type).Invoke(R, new object [] { Route });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is not happy because you are using an instance variable as a generic type.

Because the H instance variable points to a Hub instance you can replace:

```
Application.UseSignalR(R => R.MapHub<H>(Route))
```

By:

```
Application.UseSignalR(R => R.MapHub<Hub>(Route))
```

Comment: this can't work because the type 'hub' can't be instantiated.

Comment: There is no instanciation of a Hub here (abstract class), your TestHub inherits the Hub class which makes it a Hub. C# generic types are types not reference to instances.